Command runs perfectly with shell=True but not if it is set to False
I am trying to run a npm command that in turn executes another package (cypress) like e2e: cypress run. If I run this in the terminal or with shell=True it works as intended for the same environment. But since shell=True has its own security vulnerabilities and we depend on user input in the command I do not want to use it.
command = shlex.split(test_execution_script) 
#test_execution_script is derived from user input
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Upon using without shell=True it returns nNo version of Cypress is installed in: /home/ramas/.cache/Cypress/13.9.0/Cypress\n\nPlease reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install\n\n----------\n\nCypress executable not found at: /home/ramas/.cache/Cypress/13.9.0/Cypress/Cypress\n\n----------\n\nPlatform: linux-x64 (Ubuntu - 22.04)\nCypress Version: 13.9.0\n
I tried string.split() as well as shlex.split(string) and the split list is as expected and using shell=True returns desired results.

Sadly Cypress requires Nodejs not python. Why do you want to run it via python?

It is part of a larger framework that has to be in python @EvaSorhaug . Running any other npm commands works fine, its only commands that utilize cypress with shell=False that seems to give that error. Running CLI commands shouldn't be out of scope for python.

Turns out the global installation I had that was saved in /home/{usr}/.cache/Cypress was causing a problem with the dev dependency installed for whatever reason.
